# Can a voltage stepper work on "negative" voltage?

Tags: dc

I'm working on a project in which I need to supply 2-7 V using a 5 V micro controller in order to power a torquer for a satellite project.

Since I want to be able to use the same torquer to turn in both direction I'm using a H-bridge (l293d) in order to reverse the voltage.

Now for my question, as the title says, will a step-up converter ([Pololu U3V12F12](https://www.pololu.com/product/2117/specs)) be able to step up a "negative" voltage?

Comment: also, the L293D is an early 1980s H-Bridge with high losses, which leads to a low efficiency and high waste heat – simply use a better H-Bridge.

Comment: I'm using this h-bridge because I'm low on space

Comment: Then that H-Bridge is an *especially* bad choice! Its package is humongous, and in small spaces, waste heat becomes even more of a problem! Really, look at the other H-Bridges.

Comment: But more importantly: I still don't see *any* negative voltage in your system. I think you might want to add a block diagram or anything to clarify how you plan to connect things.

Comment: I don't think it's that big tbh
can u suggest a better h-bridge then?

Comment: I'm going to pass Voltage into the the h-bridge and then take the h-bridge's output to step it up but an h-bridge's out can be negetive

Comment: your comment makes no sense. I'll be blunt: thinking the L293D is a small and efficient IC, not understanding what an H-Bridge does... you should probably start smaller than doing torquer control for satellites.

Comment: In addition to choosing a horrible part you have the order of things backwards, you step up the voltage *supplied* to the H-bridge, not the output of the bridge.

Comment: actually the satellite is fully function atm, I just want the torquer to have more power

Comment: I didn't mix the order

because I don't want to burn the h-bridge I wanted to step up it's output instead of giving it higher input

Comment: @Tobies you really don't understand what you're talking about. Stepping up the *output* of an H-Bridge makes so little sense that it really shows you haven't understood what an H-Bridge does. This won't work.

Comment: thats exactly what I asked in this thread 
I didn't know if it'll work
Thats why I asked

Comment: it won't. I answered that in a comment to the answer I deleted 25 minutes ago because your question meant something else than you wrote. Also, again, learn what an H-Bridge does, then you can answer such questions yourself  – at your current level of understanding, you won't be improving a functioning system, sorry.

Comment: Anyone: what's a "torquer" in the context of a satellite?

Answer (score 3):

> Since I want to be able to use the same torquer to turn in both direction I'm using a H-bridge (l293d) in order to reverse the voltage.

That's a horribly antiquated part, and as explained just about every one of the numerous times it has been mentioned on this site, the use of Darlington transistors in it means that there is a very high voltage drop in both the high side and low side switches.  For ordinary purposes you should probably use a modern MOSFET based bridge, especially for low voltage applications.   These are now available in things like QFN packages which are much smaller and heatsink well to the board via a thermal pad.  The L293's DIP package would be particularly bad in a setting without convective air cooling.

> Now for my question, as the title says, will a step-up converter (Pololu u3v12f12) be able to step up a "negative" voltage?

No.  In theory it would be possible to build a converter which could accept input of either polarity and reflect that on the output but it would be *absurdly* complicated, and utterly unjustified.

**What you should be doing is applying any needed voltage boost *before* the H-Bridge**

> I didn't mix the order because I don't want to burn the h-bridge I wanted to step up it's output instead of giving it higher input

You obviously haven't read the L293 data sheet.  It has far more *voltage* handling capability in its ratings than it has *current* capability.

No matter what you do with it, the *thermal dissipation* of the package will still be a potential limitation given the horribly lossy design - but operating it in an higher voltage lower current regime will get more from it than operating it in a lower voltage higher current one.

You need to pick an FET bridge matched to the voltage and current requirements of your motor.  If you are going to also employ a step up voltage booster, that goes *before* the H-bridge, and will have to be selected with the behavior of the load in mind - for example, don't forget to consider that if the transducer can be mechanically rotated, it may inject power back through the H-bridge circuit and diodes to the power supply, something not all such implementations can tolerate.

It also sounds like all of this needs to be space qualified, which brings in many other concerns.   Hopefully what you are building is a sort of mock-up... if this is actually going to fly, you need expert advice from someone who is not only orders of magnitude more aware of engineering issues in general, but with spaceflight issues specifically.  If in their opinion **unique concerns of the spaceflight environment** make a bipolar solution preferable to a MOS one, they will be able to guide you in selecting a suitable solution - not only for the bridge, but *also for the voltage booster* as pretty much all of the common everyday solutions to that you might by from a hobby vendor like Pololu are also MOSFET based.